# What is this graph called?

Tags: data-visualization

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGUjB.jpg]

Sorry for the game-image link, I've wondered what this diamond-shaped graph is called for some time, any idea what type of chart/graph this is?

Comment: I'm confused how the example you give is a "data-visualization" at all, do you perhaps have a screen shot where the values very between the spokes?

Comment: Your example would have conveyed more if all the stats hadn't been the same. It's one of these - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart - Excel will do these, as will numerous other pieces of software. It's a wrapped-around version of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a [Radar Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) or Spider chart or Circular Area Chart

[Here a list of some charts and when to commonly use it](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GG8sLbThV2A/T4xp3xrbjeI/AAAAAAAAAPA/VMqnoLX_D7g/s1600/Thought+Starter.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it does seem to be what I am looking for, but there seems to be a lot of confusion between 'circular area' and pie charts. Is there another name for it that is more known?

Comment: Radar Chart, I updated my answer

Comment: This comment doesn't impact on your answer as an answer to the question, but your link doesn't show *all* possible charts... for example boxplots, mosaic plots, biplots just for starters are all missing.  If you want a comprehensive view of all charts it's probably better to think in terms of principles rather than enumerating them all - the "grammar of graphics" is a good start.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I changed the title to not mislead people.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't really help you with your question, but perhaps some1 might be interested in it:

I once wrote a R-function to create this kind of graph used to visualize clustering solutions. The code is available at https://github.com/neuhier/R-Stuff -> Netchart.R. And here is how you might use it:

```
require(flexclust)
d = data(dentitio)
clustering = kcca(dentitio, 3)
netchart(dentitio[,-1], clustering@cluster)
```

Guess its not elegant, but it works. :-)

[image: I called it netchart]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what it's called, but it is essentially a [parallel coordinates plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates), with the dimensions splayed out from a hexagon instead of in a row.